# 403 forbidden error on calling jenkins post api from python script

Tags: python, jenkins

I am new to jenkins , I am trying to build a python script which will build jobs externally but when I am executing it, throws 403 forbidden error for build jobs call other get APIs are working fine. Below is the python snippet.

> j=jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F', 'admin', 'admin@123' )
>
> j.get_jobs();
>
> print(j.jobs_count());
>
> print(j.get_jobs());
>
> j.build_job('demo1');

Jenkins details:
I am able to create & build jobs from UI successfully. My jenkins version is 2.237.

Other settings.

- loggedIn user can do anything.
  Csrf protection is disabled.

On other hand my friend having same script and version of jenkins is able to build job. Please help.